# How to build, in git, old project's history?

Tags: git

I have a project that I want to put onto Git. We have many old 'zip' snapshots of the project that can be used to create the basis of the putative historical lineage, plus a few even older bits, many I've still to 'find', that I'd still like to add to the history I build.

It isn't too hard to create a lineage from the newer zips [`copy, commit, copy, commit, .. etc.`] immediately, but how to graft(?) on the older history retrospectively? I'd like the history to look like I entered them chronologically, so some sort of `re-write` would probably be required.

Because the team is very small and co-located we can easily handle the change over from the draft version to the 'proper' version, so this is a practical exercise in getting started, and finessing the 'still to find' portions once everyone has started using git (I'd rather we were using git that waiting till sufficient 'history as found ;-).

So the question is how do I retrospectively graft on the early history, and then re-write the whole repo so the graft doesn't show? I know this will re-write *all* the commit SHA1 IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do what is described here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33868/script-tool-to-import-series-of-snapshots-each-being-a-new-edition-into-git-po

but add the `--date` option to `git commit` so that it will set whatever date comes from the zip file.

Comment: That looks like the one for building the initial repo. I'll probably put in a couple of merge points as we have V0, V1, V2, V3 'branches'. Next is sorting out the graft stage of the pre-V0 (which was Matlab .m files)

Comment: Sorry. Again but different.. Your link looks good [+1 +1]. It tells me how to build a sequence of commits for each of my versions. I can then graft the version sequences, as branches, together with 'merges', onto the 'master'. I still have to 'find' my old old history that was in matlab.m files, which I can add as if was a Version 0 branch(using same methods).

Comment: My extra wish list would be that git could read a zip file as if it was the git (GIT_DIR) directory.

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase -i` (interactive rebase) lets you do many useful history modifications.  Just note that doing so will mess up any branches anyone made before the rebase, causing everyone to rebase those branches as well.

Comment: I'd never thought of rebase in that light. I feel another re-read of the man page coming on.

Comment: I followed a few of the other links and I think that in this case I'll end up using the git-filter-branch approach (assuming I've understood its man page!) to do the complete re-write in one go (without interaction), after I've done the 'grafts'.